# Probability that neither of two selected members from a group is a lawyer

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Of the $700$ members of an organization, $120$ are lawyers. Two members will be selected at random. What is the probability that neither of the members selected will be a lawyer?

I know the answer is $(580\cdot 579)/(700\cdot 699)$

My work:

Let the event that the first person selected is a lawyer be A. Let the event that the second person selected is a lawyer be B.  Assume independence holds.

My approach to solving the problem is the probability that neither of the members selected will be a lawyer is 1-P(both members selected will be a lawyer)= $P(\neg A \cap \neg B)=1-P(A \cup B)=1-(P(A)+P(B))$ where $P(A \cap B)=0$.  I think the answer is 
$1-(\frac{120}{700})(\frac{119}{699})$ My solution isn't correct. Why? I assume sampling without replacement.

Comment: [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-(%5Cfrac%7B120%7D%7B700%7D)(%5Cfrac%7B119%7D%7B699%7D)+-+2*120%2F700*580%2F699)+-+(580%5Ccdot+579)%2F(700%5Ccdot+699))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability the first choice is not a lawyer is $580/700$ and the probability that given the first is not a lawyer that the second is also not a lawyer is $579/699$.  Multiply these.

Comment: so this is a bayesian problem

Comment: You need not invoke Bayes.  Just compound probability.

Answer (score 1):

The complement event of both are not lawyers is not both are lawyers. The complement is at least one is lawyer.

Also, there is no reason to believe that $P(A \cap B)=0$ are disjoint.

Comment: How do you find the probability that of two people there is at least one lawyer?

Comment: I am just poiting out some mistakes in your statements since you asked why isn't your answer correct. The fastest way is to solve the problem directly as described by the other answer.